# C Threaded Programming - Incrementing a shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Hey guys...so I'm trying to brush up on my C threads and a question I've found is this:

Given a global variable int x = 0; implement the function void useless(int n) which creates n threads which in a loop increase x by 1, each thread terminates when x reaches 100.

I just don't have a handle on threads and need a solid example to base my foundation. This must use pthread system calls as much as possible.

Comment: So what you tried to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing things like googling for pthreads example?

Comment: You should also specify which operating system you're targeting. Unix/POSIX uses pthreads, MS/Windows uses its own API.

Comment: @Loadmaster "This must use pthread system calls as much as possible." seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to decide what it is you're trying to achieve, and what ways possible the instructions of different threads can interlace an prevent that happening.

The incrementation operator in C `++x` is usually implemented as read the value of i from memory into an register; increment the register; write the value to memory:

```
    r1 ← xglobal
    r1 ← r1 + 1
    xglobal ← r1
```

So the value of x<sub>global</sub> is incremented by one.

If you have two threads in parallel, then they can interlace destructively

```
    initial xglobal = 99

    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
                    r2 ← xglobal          
                    compare r2 100 
    r1 ← r1 + 1  == 100 
                    r2 ← r2 + 1 == 100
    xglobal ← r1    == 100
                    xglobal ← r2     == 100
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    stop
                    r2 ← xglobal     
                    compare r1 100 
                    stop
    final xglobal = 100
```

So the value of x<sub>global</sub> is incremented by one, despite both threads incrementing it.

( I'm eliding the effects of caching, which mean that the read of a variable in thread 2 can behave as though it took place before a write in thread 1 even if the write by thread 1 happens before the read in by wall clock time. Acquiring and releasing of mutexes in pthreads cause memory barriers which force all reads to behave as though they happened after and writes to behave as if they happened before the acquire or release. )

( the above is equivalent of `for ( int r; ( r = x ) < 100; x = r + 1 )` rather than `for (;  x < 100; x = x + 1 )` which may have an extra read of x and so has another point where threads can interfere )

Similarly, an increment by one thread can destroy the increment of another thread allowing threads to end with i < 100:

```
    initial xglobal = 98
                    r2 ← xglobal          
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    r1 ← r1 + 1  == 99
    xglobal ← r1     
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    r1 ← r1 + 1  == 100
    xglobal ← r1     
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    stop
                    compare r2 100 
                    r2 ← r2 + 1 == 99
                    xglobal ← r2      
                    ...
    final xglobal = 99
```

So the second increment by the left thread is overwritten by the increment by the first, and it would terminate with the global visible value of x < 100.

You probably know all that, and may want to use a mechanism to protect against it.

I say 'may' as your requirements aren't clear - the thread above terminated when x reached 100; the requirements don't say it doesn't say there.

So, since no thread will terminate without writing x<sub>global</sub> ← 100, the requirement may in fact be met without any locking, but `x` may be incremented `n`*100 times rather than 100 times. ( if the limit was larger than a byte then the writing of x might be non-atomic on some platforms, which could result in an infinite loop if bytes from different threads are mixed together, but for a limit of 100 that won't happen )

One technique is to use a [mutex](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html) which blocks other threads from running when one thread holds the lock on the mutex. If the lock is acquired before x<sub>global</sub> is read, and not released until x<sub>global</sub> is written, then the reads and writes of the thread cannot interlace.

```
    initial xglobal = 98

    lock (mutex) 
    mutex locked 
                    lock(mutex) 
                    blocked 
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    r1 ← r1 + 1  == 99
    xglobal ← r1     

    release ( mutex )
                    mutex locked

                    r2 ← xglobal          
                    compare r2 100 
                    r2 ← r2 + 1 == 100
                    xglobal ← r2      

                    release ( mutex )

    lock (mutex) 
    mutex locked 
    r1 ← xglobal     
    compare r1 100 
    release ( mutex )
    stop
                    ...
    final xglobal = 100
```

Outside of pthreads, you might want to use your platform's compare-and-swap operation ( `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins) ) which takes an address an old value and a new value, and atomically sets the memory at the address to the new value if it was equal to the old value. This lets you write the logic as:

```
for ( int v = 0; v < 100; ) {
    int x_prev = __sync_val_compare_and_swap ( &x, v, v + 1 );

    // if the CAS succeeds, the value of x has been set to is x_prev + 1
    // otherwise, try again from current last value
    if ( x_prev == v ) 
        v = x_prev + 1;
    else
        v = x_prev;
}
```

So if

```
    initial xglobal = 98
    initial v1  = 0
    initial v2  = 0

    cmp v1  100
    x_prev1 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 98 ( set fails with x == 98 )

                    cmp v2  100
                    x_prev2 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 98 ( set fails with x == 98 )

    v1 ← x_prev1 = 98 // x_prev != v
                    v2 ← x_prev2 = 98
                    cmp v2  100
                    x_prev2 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 98 ( set succeeds with x == 99 )

                    v2 ← x_prev2 + 1 = 99 // as x_prev == v

    cmp v1  100
    x_prev1 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 99 ( set fails with x == 99 )
    v1 ← x_prev1 = 99 // as x_prev != v

    cmp v1  100
    x_prev1 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 99 ( set succeeds with x == 100)
    v1 ← x_prev1 + 1 = 100 // as x_prev == v

                    cmp v2  100
                    x_prev2 ← CASV ( xglobal, v1, v1 + 1 ) = 100 ( set fails with x == 100 )

                    v2 ← x_prev2  = 100 // as x_prev != v
    cmp v1  100
                    cmp v2  100
    stop
                    stop
```

On each loop, x<sub>global</sub> will *atomically* be set to the value of r<sub>1</sub> + 1 if and only if its previous value was r<sub>1</sub>; if not, r<sub>1</sub> will be set to the value of x<sub>global</sub> tested during the CASV operation. This reduces the amount of time locks are held on most implementations ( though it still requires locking the memory bus for the duration of the CAS operation, only those operations will be serialised. As performing the CAS is expensive on multi-cores, it probably won't be much better for such a simple case as this. )

Comment: and in a few years we will have the C1x standard which will include atomics! (as well as what is clearly a pthreads inspired threading library)

Answer (score 2):

You need a mutex to protect the variable.
Each thread will lock the mutex, increment the variable and release the mutex.
Each thread that doesn't do this is a rogue thread.

Comment: I think that the InterlockedIncrement API doesn't use a mutext; instead it just uses a `LOCK:` opcode prefix.

Comment: I don't think InterlockedIncrement alone will cut it here, since you have to protect the compare against 100 as well as the increment.

Comment: @ChrisW: can you provide a context for the InterlockedIncrement API?  @Pete: InterlockedIncrement is not a standard part of C, nor is it a part of POSIX.  The POSIX thread primitives start 'pthread_'.  You can write one easily enough - but it is not standard.

Comment: @ChrisW: also, what is the 'LOCK:' prefix?  That is a label in C - are you confusing C with C# perchance?

Comment: @Pete: InterlockedIncrement and simplings are part of Win32. Even if there is not a standard posix API for it in phreads most platforms have something similar. On Linux you have the atomic_add and siblings you can use, on Solaris it is atomic_add_32 and similar (man atomic_ops) and I bet you'll find them on most modern OS's (at least I have). If you want to be relatively platform independent, creating a simple .h file with defines mapping in the right implementation depending on the current platform is a piece of a cake as it is normally just a handful of calls and they work the same all over.

Comment: The LOCK prefix is applied to an x86 instruction to say the the processor bus is locked for the duration, making it into an atomic operation.

Comment: I know there's an InterlockedIncrement in win32. The OP wanted to use POSIX pthreads. Apache Portable Runtime has a portable interlocked increment, but I think the unix version used mutexes rather than mapping to all the different flavours last time I looked.

Comment: @Pete: the OP didn't say it had to be POSIX. He said "This must use pthread system calls as much as possible". As there are no atomic POSIX defined operations (that I know of), POSIX falls outside the "as much as possible" requirement. Using locks alone is not always a complete solution, you probably want the variable to be volatile as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a critical section. Under windows, this would be EnterCriticalSection, but in the pthread environment, the equivalent is `pthread_mutex_lock`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) for some pointers.

Comment: The markup also smartly allows you to use `backticks` to represent `__code__` which disables all other markup. Don't dis the SO markup unless you actually understand it.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that InterlockedIncrement is sufficient, if it is ok for each thread to exit if X >= 100.

I would never use a critical section unless I really have to as this can lead to a high level of contention. Whereas InterlockedIncrement has no contention at all, at least not that might affect over all performance.