# parallel programming in OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following piece of code.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  ++cnt[offset[i]];
}
```

where `offset` is an array of size `n` containing values in the range `[0, m)` and `cnt` is an array of size `m` initialized to 0. I use OpenMP to parallelize it as follows.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(cnt, offset) private(i)
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  ++cnt[offset[i]];
}
```

According to the discussion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533390/c-threaded-programming-incrementing-a-shared-variable), if `offset[i1] == offset[i2]` for `i1 != i2`, the above piece of code may result in incorrect `cnt`. What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(cnt, offset) private(i)
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  ++cnt[offset[i]];
}
```

contains a race-condition during the updates of the array `cnt`, to solve it you need to guarantee mutual exclusion of those updates. That can be achieved with (for instance) [#pragma omp atomic update](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu95.html) but as already pointed out in the comments:

> However, this resolves just correctness and may be terribly
> inefficient due to heavy cache contention and synchronization needs
> (including false sharing). The only solution then is to have each
> thread its private copy of cnt and reduce these copies at the end.

The alternative solution is to have a private array *per* thread, and at end of the parallel region you perform the manual reduction of all those arrays into one. An example of such approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421200/1366871).

Fortunately, with [OpenMP 4.5](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu95.html) you can reduce arrays using a dedicate pragma, namely:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:cnt)
```

You can have look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714116/1366871) on how to apply that feature.

Worth mentioning that regarding the reduction of arrays *versus* the atomic approach as kindly point out by [@Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard):

> Note that this is fast only if the array is not huge (the atomic based
> solution could be faster in this specific case regarding the platform
> and if the values are not conflicting). So that is m << n. –

As always profiling is the key!; Hence, you should test your code with aforementioned approaches to find out which one is the most efficient.